# How can I test the syntax of a single nix file?

Tags: nix

How can I test the syntax of a single nix file? To check if it compiles correctly.

Often I'm working on a Nixos config and it would be useful to have a faster way to check for syntax errors as opposed to `nixos-rebuild build` as it takes at least a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax/compile errors will be shown with the following command:

`nix repl 'path/to/file.nix'`